# Does applying noise reduction filters e.g. the Gaussian Filter make the images better for analysis?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I am completing a project in college about robotic perception and the mathematics behind it. I am currently looking into computer vision as a means of robotic perception and image/video feed analysis. I have stumbled upon noise reduction filters such as the Median, Bilateral and Gaussian filter after some experimenting with the OpenCV library but wanted to know if applying these filters made it easier for the images to be analysed. For example, if I were to perform Houghlines on an image to find lines, would it be useful to reduce noise in an image beforehand? Are there any applications of noise reduction for computer vision? I cannot find anything online and imagine that it may have some uses but am not sure.

I am talking about ordinary photographs that a robot may take with a camera to then use for object recognition. For example, if a robot were to determine between two types of animals in an image based on certain mathematically specified criteria, would it be helpful to reduce the noise in an image so that the image and the animals are easier to detect? I understand that this also blurs the image and edges can be lost/reduced. If noise filters are not helpful in this type of scenario, are there any you can think of that it may be useful for in terms of enabling a robot to intepret an image more accurately.

I apologise if this is not clear, this area of knowledge is something I am unfamiliar with and is something I am pushing myself to understand to include in my project.

Comment: Simply put, sometimes it's helpful, sometimes it's not. The use case for any particular filter is heavily dependent on your processing chain, the size of your images, and the type of your images (binary? photographs? computer drawn with heavy aliasing? etc). As this question stands it is too broad for the Stack Overflow Q/A format. If you can edit your question to provide a specific problem in code, then this question will be more likely to get responses.

Comment: The answer is application-dependent. But generally speaking, filters that remove noise also remove fine features and have a blurring effect. Not ideal for edge detection. To my knowledge, the best denoising filter is the Non-Local-Means, but it is dead slow.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds I have tried to be more specific. Is this suitable?

Comment: Not sure if it still really sits with SO format, since this site is specifically to help with *code* issues. Either way, the answer to your specific question is no---adding a blur or some other noise suppression techniques should not be added to a chain for object detection unless there's a very specific purpose (e.g. you know the characterization of the noise or something). In general object detectors are trained on tons of photographs, including noisy ones, and the convolutions they use learn to smooth things out when appropriate.